# How to make a particular sub-string Bold while printing a string in Pdf using iText in java eclipse?

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I am using iText in Java to convert a HTML to PDF.

I want a particular paragraph which has some words as Bold and some as Bold+Underlined to be passed as a string to the Java code and to be converted to PDF using the iText library.

I am unable to find a suitable method for this. How should I do this?

Comment: First feed your HTML into this demo: http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/ Then hit transform. Do you get the desired result? If so, I'll show you the code.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Can you please share the code?

Comment: See my answer. You may want to try all the examples before writing your own code.

Comment: I am following your book Bruno. It's great to hear from you.

Comment: If you refer to "iText in Action": the HTML to PDF part needs to be replaced. If you refer to "The ABC of PDF", that's a work in progress. Once that book is finished, I'll use the XML Worker examples as the basis for a book about templates for PDF.

Comment: I have you book and I have went through most of the examples here- http://itextpdf.com/book/examples.php Can you please share the code?

Comment: I think you misread my answer. Please read my answer once more and click the link in the second line.

Comment: Ya got that now. Can you please tell where can i get the required jar file?

Comment: Click on the Download button on these SourceForge projects: http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlworker/ and http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to convert XHTML to PDF, you need iText + XML Worker.

You can find a number of examples here: http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker

The most simple examples looks like this:

```
public void createPdf(String file) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    // step 1
    Document document = new Document();
    // step 2
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
    // step 3
    document.open();
    // step 4
    XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document,
            new FileInputStream(HTML));
    // step 5
    document.close();
}
```

Note that the HTML file is passed as a `FileInputStream` in this case. You want to pass a `String`. This means you'll have to do something like this:

```
XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document,
        new StringReader("<p>The <b>String</b> I want to render to PDF</p>"));
```

There are more complex examples in the Sandbox in case you need support for images, special fonts, and so on. For instance [this example](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker/D11_ParseHtmlObjects) will convert XHTML to a series of iText objects instead of rendering them to a page rightaway.