# Parse chunks of HTML with iText in loop on different pages

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, xmlworker

I currently have a working version of creating a PDF based on data from several rows in a database.  For each row in the database, it creates a new page in the PDF.  This is all working great.  Now I need to parse a few of the fields in each row so their HTML is rendered properly.  I can [see an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036662/how-to-make-a-particular-sub-string-bold-while-printing-a-string-in-pdf-using-it) which shows parsing the whole document although it's taking a whole string and parsing the document.

What I need is to create individual formatted pages with only specific fields of HTML to be parsed.  Is it possible to do this?

Below is some sample code I have which creates the new pages:

```
PdfFont fTimes = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(FontConstants.TIMES_ROMAN);
PdfFont fTimesBold = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(FontConstants.TIMES_BOLD);                    

// create the first page here
doc.Add(new Paragraph("Abstract Submissions for " + eventName).SetFont(fTimes).SetFontSize(18).SetFontColor(Color.BLACK));
doc.Add(new Paragraph("Section Name: " + GetSectionName(ddlSections.SelectedValue)).SetFont(fTimes).SetFontSize(14).SetFontColor(Color.BLACK));
doc.Add(new Paragraph("Created:  " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, MMMM d, yyyy h:mm tt")).SetFont(fTimes).SetFontSize(11).SetFontColor(Color.BLACK));

// iterate through each of the items
foreach (DataRow row in dsItems.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    // create a new page for each abstract submission
    doc.Add(new AreaBreak(iText.Layout.Properties.AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));
    doc.Add(new Paragraph(ValidationHelper.GetString(row["PresentationType"], "")).SetFont(fTimes).SetFontSize(12).SetFontColor(Color.BLACK));
    doc.Add(new Paragraph(ValidationHelper.GetString(row["PresentationTitle"], "")).SetFont(fTimes).SetFontSize(16).SetFontColor(Color.BLACK));
    // html field
    doc.Add(new Paragraph(ValidationHelper.GetString(row["Authors"], "")).SetFont(fTimes).SetFontSize(12).SetFontColor(Color.BLACK));
    // html field
    doc.Add(new Paragraph(ValidationHelper.GetString(row["Abstract"], "")).SetFont(fTimes).SetFontSize(12).SetFontColor(Color.BLACK));
}

doc.Close();
```

I should note I'm using a `MemoryStream` vs. `FileStream` so the client can download immediately, not required to save in file system.

** EDIT - adding sample data **

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Poster</td>
        <td>Abstract 1</td>
        <td><strong><em>Doctor Name 1</em></strong> <strong>Doctor Name 2</strong></td>
        <td><p>Some really long text <strong>which can have</strong> some different basic HTML <u>formatting in it</u></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Presentation</td>
        <td>Abstract 2</td>
        <td><strong>Doctor Name 15 </strong><em>Doctor 3</em></td>
        <td><p>Some really long text which can have some different basic HTML <em>formatting in it</em></p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of content that is to be parsed/rendered? Is this content some minor subset of html with consistent formatting like from a rich text editor or is it any wild html/css stuff?

Comment: I added some sample data @COeDev Sorry for the poor formatting.  Essentially everything in the <td> tags is a database column. Only way I was able to get the full effect of the markup without the editor formatting it all.

Comment: If there is not much else than "strong", "p", "em" and the html is valid xml, you can easily parse this stuff and create itext elements from it.

Comment: Yes, very simple markup as I only give them a very very basic WYSIWYG editor.   So that's what I'm looking for is how that is done.  I'm unsure as the documentation isn't very detailed IMHO.

Comment: I don't really understand what the difference is between what you have and what you want.

Comment: What the example I'm seeing is that it is parsing the whole document based on a single input string.  I only need to parse 2 bits of HTML on every page I create.  I need each row of data to be formatted like I show with different font sizes and wieghts for titles and such PLUS have any HTML input formatted as such.

Comment: Did you find a solution on this?

Comment: I haven't got back to the project yet @COeDev but plan to do some testing  on your code sample.

Answer (score 0):

With a pattern like this you can create your own xml/html to itext translator. You just need to implement the tags you need:

```
internal interface ICustomElement { IEnumerable<IElement> GetContent(); }

internal class CustomElementFactory {
  public ICustomElement GetElement(XmlNode node) {
    switch (node.Name) {
      case "p": return new CustomParagraph (node, this);
      // implement the tags you need using the ICustomElement interface
      default: // e.g. treat unknown nodes as text
    }
}

public class PdfCreator {
  public byte[] GetPdf(XmlDocument template) {
    PdfDocument doc ...
    CustomElementFactory factory ...
    foreach(XmlNode node in template.ChildNodes) {
      doc.AddElements(factory.GetElement(node).GetContent()); 
      // the point why all this is possible in such an easy generic way is that almost every itext element implements the IElement interface and therefore can be added to the document this way. And containers like PdfPCell are taking IElements as well.
      // Good job itext guys! ;)
    }

    return doc.CloseDocument();
  }
}

// here comes the magic:

internal class CustomParagraph : ICustomElement {
  // ctor storing the xmlnode and factory in private field
  public IEnumerable<IElement> GetContent() {
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
    p.Add(node.InnerText); // create a underline or bold or whatever font here when you are implementing the special html tags

    // if the node has child elements, get their content by calling the factory.GetElement(child).GetContent() for each child. Then loop over the the IElement.Chunks collection of each IElement to add the containing chunks to the paragraph of this scope. This way you will be able to process nested html tags recursively.
    // find a way to pass the style information of this scope to the factory when processing child nodes, so you will be able to render <strong>bold<u>underlindANDBOLD</u></strong> stuff correctly

    return new List<IElement> { p };
  }
}
```

This needs some work and fine tuning, but it can be done.